# How to access elements in a dictionary in python with for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to extract information from a dictionary, but can't figure how to access data.

I have:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import numpy as np

start_date = date(2017,1,1);
final_date = date.today() + relativedelta(months=2);

def datarange(start_date, final_date):
    for n in range((final_date-start_date).days+1):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

PayDayTable = {i:np.zeros(5) for i in datarange(start_date, final_date)}
```

and I can do:

```
print(PayDayTable)
print(PayDayTable[date.today()])
print(PayDayTable[date.today()][0])
print(PayDayTable[date.today()][1:3])
```

but when I do:

```
for item in PayDayTable:
    print(item)
```

How can I access the values of the `PayDayTable dictionary` by iterating over the items with `for loop`?

Edit:

I was looking for Python 2 documentation while I was using Python 3.6.

So instead of doing something like:

```
for item in PayDayTable.iteritems():
    pass
```

I've learned that I should do:

```
for item in PayDayTable.items():
    print(item[1][0])
```

Comment: read the docs about how dictionary (or hashmap) works

Comment: I was looking for Python 2 documentation while I was using Python 3.6.

So instead of doing:

    for item in PayDayTable.iteritems():
     pass

I should do:

    for item in PayDayTable.items():
     print(item[1][0])

Answer (score 2):

`type(item)` is `datetime.date`, it is not iterable (you can't do item[0]). Each element (`item` in your code) in your `PayDayTable` is a date.

If you need the dates - just work with elements of `PayDayTable`. But if you want to get the associated `value` with the `date` key by iterating the dictionary using a `for loop`, then you could do something like:

```
for item in PayDayTable:
    print(PayDayTable[item])
```

Comment: But in this case I know how to get the dates, just by iterating trough PayDayTable.
What I don't know, is how to access the elements associates with each date by a for iteration.

Comment: `for item in PayDayTable:`
    `print(PayDayTable[item])`